# Power BI - model view - query already exists

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a new Query in the model view called "Metrics".  It tells me that "The table couldn't be renamed.  A query called metrics already exists."  I cannot see this phantom table anywhere.  Why does Power BI think it's there?

The first image is the Power BI Report View, with my table currently called "Metrix".

[image]

The second shows the error message when I try to rename it to "Metrics".

[image]

Comment: maybe some screenshots would help..

Comment: Error said you are going to create a table with name "Metrix" where as there is already a table with same name.

Comment: Updated spelling error in original question.   Also, to clarify, when I started to create this report, I did have a query called "Metrics", very briefly, but I deleted it (at least I thought I had).  This is the reason that I created the query called "Metrix".  It doesn't matter too much here, as it's only a training exercise, but I would like to get to the bottom of it for future reference.

Comment: Could it be that if you go to **Transform Data** the query "Metrics" is found under the queries, but is disabled? It would then not show up under the **Fields** view of your first screenshot.